# \per\kWh produces a wrong output

Tags: siunitx

I want to say 10 cent dollar per kilowatt-hour of electricity. When I compile the following,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI[per-mode=symbol]{0.1}[\$]{\per\kWh}
\end{document}
```

I get the following result that is not correct.

[image]

The correct output must be as follows:

[image]

This is a bug or I forgot something to setup?

Comment: Did you try something like `\SI[per-mode=symbol]{0.1}{\$\per\kWh}`?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: The output is not exactly the same as what I want to get.

Comment: But why do you want `dollar-cent 10 per kilowatt-hour`? The comment from @ClaudioFiandrino looks like the correct solution to me

Comment: @matth: Because I want to say not I want to write. :-) The usual format is currency sign followed by a number per unit.

Comment: Ok, but you are aware that the solution by @ClaudioFiandrino is the common way of writing it? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_pricing

Comment: @matth: It depends on the culture, each country has different format. I prefer the currency sign comes before the number. Anyway, it is not the main problem but I am focusing on the problem why `\per\kWh` produces a wrong output.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that kWh is a combined unit of watt and hours with a kilo prefix. So if you wirte `\kWh` it expands to `\kilo\watt\hour` and the `\per` will be applied to the `\watt` part only.

### Solution 1

Use the `sticky-per` option to get `\per\hour` to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI[per-mode=symbol,sticky-per]{0.1}[\$]{\per\kWh}
\end{document}
```

[image: with parens]

Adding `bracket-unit-denominator = false` will suppress the parens.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI[%
    per-mode=symbol,sticky-per,
    bracket-unit-denominator=false,
]{0.1}[\$]{\per\kWh}
\end{document}
```

[image: suppressed parens]

### Solution 2

Overwrite the definition of `\kWh`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareSIUnit{\kWh}{kWh}}

\begin{document}
\SI[per-mode=symbol]{0.1}[\$]{\per\kWh}
\end{document}
```

[image: overwritten unit macro]

### Conclusion

Decide wether you think kWh is a combine unit or not. If you think it is, use Solution 1 if you see it as a single unit use solution 2.

Comment: I see. And can it be regarded as a bug?

Comment: @Forgiver: Hm … depends on you point of view. I you take kWh as a single unit it’s a bug, if you take it as a combined unit, it’s no bug …

Comment: Sorry, there is an unnecessary space between capital `W` and `h`.

Comment: @Forgiver this is no bug! The [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/siunitx) even has a short section about the `\kWh` unit (section 7.12 “Special considerations for the `\kWh` unit”). The space -- which is common between units -- is discussed there as well.

Comment: @Forgiver No, that's not unnecessary. I warn in the docs that the usual use of 'kWh' with no space is very questionable, as it hides the multiplication (kilowatts times hours). There is a specific note about combining `\kWh` with other items.

Comment: @Tobi I'd say this is the design behaviour. A 'prebuilt' unit such as `\kWh` is intended as a shortcut for `\kilo\watt\hour` to be used if you have a lot of them. It's not really the intention that combinations of 'combined' units can then be used to build up further complexity as it then makes the powers complex. For example, what would `\kWh\squared` mean? I strongly favour writing things out, as it's rarely a significant increase in input complexity. Of course, if there is demand I can think about extending the parser, perhaps with an option to affect the behaviour.

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks for this comment :-) I’d prefer the per build definition too, but it’s easy to overwrite it and get `\kWh` without space [my solution 2].

Comment: @cgnieder and others: I am an impatient user who have just read the impatient section of the documentation. I did not know the answer is already available there. This is my bad: making many experiments without reading the manual.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, this idea came from [Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304/claudio-fiandrino)'s comment. I compiled his code and I noticed I got a correct output but with different position of currency sign.

A funny way to solve it, just append `\null` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI[per-mode=symbol]{0.1}[\$]{\null\per\kWh}
\end{document}
```

Because I am still interested in why this way works, I leave this post as is until someone can explain the reason. Of course this post is not regarded as the answer!

Comment: I understood that this answer deserves a -1 for not having a scientific basis. I will not accept it until there is a worse one.